# GWT says robots.txt is blocking resources - mine or theirs?

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console

In Google Webmaster Tools when I 'Fetch as Google' it tells me there are 2 blocked resources which are blocked by robots.txt:

- `https://dash.reviews.co.uk/[cut]`
- `https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/[cut]`

But I cannot see how these are blocked in my robots.txt, which contains the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /category/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /tools/
```

Any clues?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114519/google-search-console-reports-blocked-resources-from-doubleclick-while-rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about those resources being blocked because those are on domains that you don't control and is being blocked by their robots.txt files.

Google Webmaster Tools is showing you that for the page you had it fetch, it can't see all the resources which is fairly common. Google and many large sites robots.txt many of their resources. (DoubleClick is a Google owned property)

As long as you can see the entirety of your content when you "fetch and render" you're in good shape.